# pagination not happening in vf page

Tags: visualforce, jquery, pagination

I am trying to paginate using footable plugin, but somehow pagination is not happening. Can anybody help me out -

```
<apex:page sidebar="false">
<head>

 <meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial-scale = 1.0, minimum-scale = 1.0, maximum-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no"/>
 <apex:includescript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"/>
 <apex:includeScript value="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-footable/0.1.0/js/footable.js"/>
 <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.footable,'footable.paginate.js?v=2-0-1')}"/>
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.footable,'bootstrap-tab.js')}"/>  
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.footable,'demos.js')}"/>  

 <script>
        if (!window.jQuery) { document.write('<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"><\/script>'); }
    </script>
  <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.footable,'footable.core.css?v=2-0-1')}"/>
  <apex:stylesheet value="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-footable/0.1.0/css/footable.min.css"/>
  <apex:stylesheet value="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
  <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.footable,'footable-demos.css')}"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="demo-container">
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="demo">
                <table class="table demo" data-page-size="5" >
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th data-toggle="true">
                                First Name
                            </th>   
                            <th>
                                Last Name
                            </th>
                            <th data-hide="phone,tablet">
                                Job Title
                            </th>
                            <th data-hide="phone,tablet">
                                DOB
                            </th>
                            <th data-hide="phone">
                                Status
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Isidra</td>
                            <td><a href="#">Boudreaux</a></td>
                            <td>Traffic Court Referee</td>
                            <td data-value="78025368997">22 Jun 1972</td>
                            <td data-value="1"><span class="status-metro status-active" title="Active">Active</span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Shona</td>
                            <td>Woldt</td>
                            <td><a href="#">Airline Transport Pilot</a></td>
                            <td data-value="370961043292">3 Oct 1981</td>
                            <td data-value="2"><span class="status-metro status-disabled" title="Disabled">Disabled</span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Granville</td>
                            <td>Leonardo</td>
                            <td>Business Services Sales Representative</td>
                            <td data-value="-22133780420">19 Apr 1969</td>
                            <td data-value="3"><span class="status-metro status-suspended" title="Suspended">Suspended</span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Easer</td>
                            <td>Dragoo</td>
                            <td>Drywall Stripper</td>
                            <td data-value="250833505574">13 Dec 1977</td>
                            <td data-value="1"><span class="status-metro status-active" title="Active">Active</span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Maple</td>
                            <td>Halladay</td>
                            <td>Aviation Tactical Readiness Officer</td>
                            <td data-value="694116650726">30 Dec 1991</td>
                            <td data-value="3"><span class="status-metro status-suspended" title="Suspended">Suspended</span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Maxine</td>
                            <td><a href="#">Woldt</a></td>
                            <td><a href="#">Business Services Sales Representative</a></td>
                            <td data-value="561440464855">17 Oct 1987</td>
                            <td data-value="2"><span class="status-metro status-disabled" title="Disabled">Disabled</span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Lorraine</td>
                            <td>Mcgaughy</td>
                            <td>Hemodialysis Technician</td>
                            <td data-value="437400551390">11 Nov 1983</td>
                            <td data-value="2"><span class="status-metro status-disabled" title="Disabled">Disabled</span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Lizzee</td>
                            <td><a href="#">Goodlow</a></td>
                            <td>Technical Services Librarian</td>
                            <td data-value="-257733999319">1 Nov 1961</td>
                            <td data-value="3"><span class="status-metro status-suspended" title="Suspended">Suspended</span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Judi</td>
                            <td>Badgett</td>
                            <td>Electrical Lineworker</td>
                            <td data-value="362134712000">23 Jun 1981</td>
                            <td data-value="1"><span class="status-metro status-active" title="Active">Active</span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Lauri</td>
                            <td>Hyland</td>
                            <td>Blackjack Supervisor</td>
                            <td data-value="500874333932">15 Nov 1985</td>
                            <td data-value="3"><span class="status-metro status-suspended" title="Suspended">Suspended</span></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="5">
                                <div class="pagination pagination-centered"></div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="setup">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('table').footable();

            $('.clear-filter').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $('table.demo').trigger('footable_clear_filter');
                $('.filter-status').val('');
            });

            $('.filter-status').change(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var filter = $(this).val();
                $('#filter').val($(this).text());
                $('table.demo').trigger('footable_filter', {filter: filter});
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</apex:page>
```

[image]
Regards

Comment: Add one more item in the list and then the pagination should kick in.. From the docs it looks like the default page size is 10 records. Also, since this is related to a specifc jQuery plugin, it is always better to post it in stackoverflow than SFSE for better responses.

Comment: Hi theGreatDanton, I am trying this code in vf page. After setting the size to 5, still pagination is not working. Can u please check by copy pasting the code in salesforce..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always ideal to have all the resources refer to locally stored static resources for two reasons:

- It is relatively faster to fetch the resource which has been stored locally.
- The resource present online might be changed while you are still using it and may cause some aberrant behavior.

Here, in your case, the pagination issue could be bcoz of the reason that footable.js is loaded from the external resource and not from the static resource.